Random frames in EEVEE animation render have extra or fewer lights
I am rendering out an EEVEE animation in 4.3 and get random frames with brighter or possibly extra lights. If I re-render the specific frames they seem to render fine, but this would be tedious with a large number of frames to correct. Is there a known reason/fix for this light glitch? I've read that there were bloom setting issues in the past, but since bloom is no longer a render setting I am at a loss. Happy to share the file. Thank you!

can you share the .blend file? Also have you tried testig the same issue on 4.2? This may be worth reporting as a bug to Blender foundation https://projects.blender.org/

Here's a guide on how to upload your file: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3050/how-to-upload-a-blend-file-on-bse-good-practices-and-advice

Great, thank you! I haven't had a chance to try in 4.2 yet, but here is the file I'm working with in 4.3.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gw45ncodtex9exy9618gp/TurkeyMan-Animation-sample.blend?rlkey=mmxdtwcf3yuju4k08v89qoufv&st=oudg5jn3&dl=0
